# using regexp_replace to transform numbers into strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to use regexp_replace replace every occurrence of type (number) (brackets with a number inside) with the expression ('number') (add ' before and after the number and by that - transform the number into varchar).

Example -

Before change: abcde(737)sbsgs37(6)s(v)

After change : abcde('737')sbsgs37('6')s(v)

Thanks,

Ilya Golosovsky.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: The input data is a `VARCHAR2` containing alphabetical characters, punctuation and numbers - how will wrapping the numbers in quotes within a `VARCHAR2` type magically change parts of the string to a `NUMBER` type such that wrapping them in quotes will make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one

```
regexp_replace('abcde(737)sbsgs37(6)s(v)', '\((\d+)\)', '(''\1''))

-> abcde('737')sbsgs37('6')s(v)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/10493)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this doesn't suite my case.  You're targeting any number, I just need the want the ones in brackets.

Comment: I changed it (using less brackets than @pablomatico)

Answer (score 1):

All credit for Wernfried Domscheit as he just missed one little thing. You could use this one:

```
regexp_replace('abcde(737)sbsgs37(6)s(v)', '(\()(\d+)(\))', '\1''\2''\3')
```

Tested and worked:

```
select regexp_replace('abcde(737)sbsgs37(6)s(v)', '(\()(\d+)(\))', '\1''\2''\3') from dual
```

Comment: Since you've already captured the parens, you could use those in the output instead of hardcoding more: `select regexp_replace('abcde(737)sbsgs37(6)s(v)', '(\()(\d+)(\))', '\1''\2''\3') from dual;`.

Comment: Thanks @Gary_W! You're right I just edited the answer.